# Eclipse hover variable debug never working for local variables

Tags: java, eclipse

During the debuging, most of time i am forced to select a variable and right click display to see its value.

for exemple for `this`, it always works, but never for local variables? (or lets say most of time)

here its working (without right click display):
[image]

here its not !? :
[image]

Comment: do you tried Display console?

Comment: i dont see what you mean, i said that it can be done with right click display but, i want to know why some times the hover works and some times not?!